# Dynamically building an "array of strcuts" in Python

Tags: python

I am parsing a XML document, looking for items which describe function calls.

When I find a node with a function call, it can have zero or more parameters, but I cannot know how many until I have processed them all - so, no pre-sizing of data structures.

Also, the `description` for each parameter might be blank.

I am trying to create something like:

```
numParams = 0
for each param in fucntionNode:
   params[numParams]['name'] = xxx  # from the XML which we are parsing
   # or, do I mean ...
   params[numParams].name = xxx
   # also get param type and description
   numParams += 1
```

When all parameters have been processed, I can do something with the `params` data structure.

I *think* that each entry in `param` should be a dictionary, but I am unsure how to dynamically build an "array" of them.

Can someone please tell me how to pythonically declare the appropriate data structure, to add to it and, afterwards, to access it?

And, unfortunately, I need to index when accessing afterwards. E.g. `params[[2]['name']`

Comment: define a `param` structure and `list.append(param_structure)`

Comment: define a `class` to describe the param, or use a `dict`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not clear what exactly you need (where does `xxx` come from param?). It may be as simple as this

```
params = []
for param in functionNode:
   params.append({'name': xxx})
```

or

```
params = [{'name': xxx} for param in functionNode]
```

or should it be

```
params = [{'name': xxx, 'type': yyy, 'desc': zzz} for param in functionNode]
```

---

[Answer] OP here, I hope you don't mind me appending this for clarity. I have changed nothing of your answer (above).

I used your first option:

```
params = []
for idx, param in enumerate(functionNode):
   # parse XML and assign local variables type, name & description
   params.append({'name': name, 'type': type, 'description': description})
```

and I can access later as

```
params[2]['name']
```

Comment: the XXX comes from the XML which I cam parsing - three fields for each parameter, although the description can be blank.  And, unfortunately, I need to index when accessing afterwards. E.G `params[[2]['name']`

Comment: @Mawg get the index with `enumerate`

Comment: @Mawg, i edited your edit to make the index available during the loop, or did you just mean you need to access the resulting list by index? In that case you already can.

Comment: Actually, I only need to access by index after the loop is complete, but your edit is helpful to others who read this in future